# How to find the highest sums from several groups of numbers

Tags: combinatorics

What is the equation or a way to figure out what the highest possible sum is from several group of numbers.

For example, If i had 4 groups of numbers, and in each group the numbers 0-10 occur. how can you add those numbers up to the highest outcomes. an easy way of explaining is in a car race. There are 4 races, and 10 participents in the race. Winning the race gives 10 points, second gives 9 and so on. What would the highest possible score be for someone to have and yet still be the losing racer. Is there a concrete equation for this problem that works for any set of numbers?

Comment: $0-10$ is involves eleven possible scores but you say there are ten participants

Comment: It sounds like the process would depend on the exact nature of the way that the number was specified. In your example, you would also need to figure out how anyone could get a higher score when someone scores $37$. There might be some pigeonhole reasoning, etc.

Comment: @Joffan Clearly $10+10+10+9=39 > 37=9+9+9+10$.  This is not too difficult to generalise if you adjust for parity. $(10+10+10+8=38>37$ would also work, but need not be considered$)$

Comment: @Henry Obviously I gave the number $37$ in order to prompt that kind of thought process. And then $38$ would also need to be eliminated as a second-place score, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your example of $c=10$ competitiors and $r=4$ races with points $c=10,9,\ldots,1$ each race, you can say:

- $\frac12c(c+1)=55$ points are distributed in each race
- $\frac12rc(c+1)=220$ points are distributed in total
- The average number of points per racer in total is therefore $\frac12r(c+1)=22$
- It is possible in this case for one racer to get $\frac12r(c+1)+1=23$ points in total and all the others $22$ except for one who gets $21$.  In some other competitions (an even number of racers and an odd number of races) to have a clear overall winner might require them to have a total $1.5$ points above average.  So we could say $\big\lceil \frac12r(c+1)+1\big\rceil$ as the minimum number of points needed to be a clear winner in general
- The lowest second place total which not tied with others is $\big\lceil \frac12rc+1\big\rceil=21$, essentially the same as the previous result but ignoring the top place winner of every race.  The lowest second place total which might be tied with lower positions is $\big\lceil \frac12rc\big\rceil =20$ here.
- The highest total possible points is $rc=40$ points here.  If somebody scores this then the next highest possible is $r(c-1)=36$, but it is possible to narrow this gap by transferring points between the top two overall until they are almost equal.
- The highest second place total here must be strictly below $r\left(c-\frac12\right)=38$ if it must be strictly less than the points won by the  top overall place, so cannot be higher than $37$ here.  Let's call this $$\bigg\lfloor r\left(c-\frac12\right) -\frac12\bigg\rfloor$$ as the general expression for the highest possible score for somebody clearly second top overall.